# Restore an image blurred with MATLAB's imgaussfilt function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, blur, deconvolution, gaussianblur

I'm working to restore a blurred image without knowing the PSF value. I used blind deconvolution to estimate the PSF value and Lucy Richardson method to completely restore the image. The thing is, I used `fspecial('gaussian')` to blur the image and now I need to use `imgaussfilt` function to do that. But once I do that, the image does not restore as expected. With the first method, I got excellent results.

What is the difference between `fspecial('gaussian')` and `imgaussfilt()`? Is there a way I can restore an image blurred with the second function?

PS: All the images are iris pictures used in a biometric system.

---

First I tried the restoration process using this code:

```
function [J, P, V] = blindDeconv(image, qualityBlur, upTo)
lowerValue = 20;
for i = 3:15
    for j = 1:upTo
        P = fspecial('gaussian', i, j);
        [I PSF] = deconvblind(image,P);
        %[I PSF] = deblur(image, j);
        quality = blurMetric(I);
        if quality < lowerValue
            lowerValue = quality;
            P = PSF;
            J = I;
            V = j;
        end
    end
end
```

And this is the main script where I blur and deblur the image:

```
%----------------------
%  Blurring process
%----------------------
%PSF = fspecial('gaussian', 7, j);
%blur{i,j} = imfilter(im2double(image{i}), PSF, 'conv');
blur{i,j} = imgaussfilt(im2double(image{i}), j);
qualityBlur{i, j} = blurMetric(blur{i, j});
link = strcat(folder, '/', prefix, '_blur_', num2str(j), '.jpeg');
imwrite(blur{i, j}, link, 'jpeg');

%---------------------
% Deblurring process
%----------------------
[J, P, V] = blindDeconv(blur{i, j}, qualityBlur{i, j}, upTo);
deblurred{i, j} = deconvlucy(J, P, 20, V);
qualityDeblurred{i, j} = blurMetric(deblurred{i, j});
link = strcat(folder, '/', prefix, '_deblur_', num2str(j), '.jpeg');
imwrite(deblurred{i, j}, link, 'jpeg');
```

**Image sample:**

[image: sample]

Comment: Please provide us the code you tried including a sample image. In the meantime, you may have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695132/image-deblurring-using-gaussian-filter-in-matlab-without-additive-noise/42706938#42706938).

Comment: I added the code, and thanks I'll take a look !!